# How to identify the GitHub page header logo invertocat using selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, svg, selenium-webdriver, xpath

For learning purpose I am trying to simulate GitHub using selenium.

I am unable to locate the GitHub page header logo invertocat for GitHub homepage button.

I have tried with : `find_element_by_class_name`, `find_element_by_css_selector` and `find_element_by_xpath` but nothing worked.

I am not sure if my value's are wrong.

Here's the html version of that button from inspect element :

```html
<svg height="32" class="octicon octicon-mark-github" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1" width="32" aria-hidden="true"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 0C3.58 0 0 3.58 0 8c0 3.54 2.29 6.53 5.47 7.59.4.07.55-.17.55-.38 0-.19-.01-.82-.01-1.49-2.01.37-2.53-.49-2.69-.94-.09-.23-.48-.94-.82-1.13-.28-.15-.68-.52-.01-.53.63-.01 1.08.58 1.23.82.72 1.21 1.87.87 2.33.66.07-.52.28-.87.51-1.07-1.78-.2-3.64-.89-3.64-3.95 0-.87.31-1.59.82-2.15-.08-.2-.36-1.02.08-2.12 0 0 .67-.21 2.2.82.64-.18 1.32-.27 2-.27.68 0 1.36.09 2 .27 1.53-1.04 2.2-.82 2.2-.82.44 1.1.16 1.92.08 2.12.51.56.82 1.27.82 2.15 0 3.07-1.87 3.75-3.65 3.95.29.25.54.73.54 1.48 0 1.07-.01 1.93-.01 2.2 0 .21.15.46.55.38A8.013 8.013 0 0 0 16 8c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8z"></path></svg>
```

This homepage button I am trying to access

and the github link of the pictures page is: https://github.com/Imran4424

[image]

Comment: Update the question with which `GitHub homepage button` exactly are you trying to locate?

Comment: i edited the question with a picture from which page i am trying to go to homepage @DebanjanB

Answer (score 0):

The element you are trying to locate is an `<svg>` element which is from the [**SVG namespace**](https://www.w3.org/2000/svg) and you can use the following *XPATH* :

```
//header[@class='Header  f5']//a[@class='header-logo-invertocat']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='path']
```

Snapshot :

[image: svg]

Comment: element_home = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//header[@class='Header  f5']//a[@class='header-logo-invertocat']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='path'])

Comment: @ImranHossain You need to pass the `xpath` value as a `String` within double quotes i.e. `""`. You can validate the `xpath` through the _Development Tools Console_ as well.

Comment: exceptions: Unable to locate element: //header[@class='Header  f5']//a[@class='header-logo-invertocat']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='path']

Comment: @ImranHossain Did you validate the `xpath` through the _Development Tools Console_?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, how to do it

Comment: @ImranHossain Then how did you inspect the elements to construct `find_element_by_class_name`, `find_element_by_css_selector` and `find_element_by_xpath` as you mentioned in your question?

Comment: I inspect element using Firefox then copy the xpath and CSS selector and for class name i saw it in html format

Comment: Great !!! Likewise, go to the `inspect element` stage using Firefox, press `Control` + `F`, in the search box paste the `xpath` I have provided and let me know the result.

Comment: @ImranHossain Check through _Chrome Development Tool Console_